# Do code if this code runs

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I want to run code if another code snippet has run.

**IF** this code runs

```
(function() {
// Code runs here
})();
```

**THEN** run this code also

```
//This code
```

**Example**

```
if (condition) {
    block of code to be executed if the condition is true
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else

This won't seem to work?

```
if ((function() {// Code runs here})();) 
    {
        //This code
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use return statement otherwise the IIFE would return undefined and thus it would be equivalent to false statement.

```
if (
(function() {
   // Code runs here
   return true;

})();
){
  //This code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
var functionName = (function() {
  var didRun = false;

  // This function will be executed only once, no matter how many times
  // it is called.
  function functionName() {
    // Your code goes here
  }

  return function() {
    if (didRun) {
      return;
    }

    didRun = true;

    return foo.apply(this, arguments);
  }
})();
```

and check, when the function didRun, then execute your core

Answer (score 0):

The IIFE seems superfluous to me here - just use a named function the simple way and keep it straightforward.  If anyone can give me a use for the IIFE as the conditional expression in an If ... else, please comment - I would love to understand what I might be missing:

```js
function odd(num) {
  return num % 2;
}

// Use Dev Tools Console (F12) to see output
function logOddEven(num) {
  if (odd(num)) {
    console.log(num + ' is odd');
  } else {
    console.log(num + ' is even');
  }
}

logOddEven(0);
logOddEven(1);
logOddEven(2);
```